# Error in QPackage in QGIS 3.12

Tags: qgis, plugins, layer-package

What does this error message mean:

> AttributeError: 'QLineEdit' object has no attribute 'toPlainText'

I get this every time I try to run the QPackage Plugin.

Answer (score 2):

If you refer to the Qt documentation ([QLineEdit - Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QLineEdit.html)) the **QLineEdit** widget has no `toPlainText()` function.

This is a method that can be used with the **QTextEdit** widget ([QTextEdit - Qt](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html)).

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the QPackage plugin and make it work like a charm (great package!) by opening the package file, QPackage_dialog.py, for me it was here:

```
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\QPackage
```

Two simple changes will make this file/QPackage compatible with the new QGIS version:
(make sure to restart QGIS after changing and saving the file)

1. Add `import shutil` to the import statement on top
2. Change `self._repertoire.toPlainText()` into `self._repertoire.text()` around lines 134 to 141 (three times), as follows:

```
    elif layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.RasterLayer:
        layer.__class__ = QgsRasterLayer
        if(self._repertoire.text() != ""):
            if os.name == 'nt':
                shutil.copy2(layer.publicSource(), self._repertoire.text() + "\\" + os.path.basename(layer.publicSource()))
            else:
                shutil.copy2(layer.publicSource(), self._repertoire.text() + "/" + os.path.basename(layer.publicSource()))
```

Comment: I have a similar problem on Windows but not on Mac with the toMarkdown() method. Is there an equivalent?

Comment: This addresses the current error. But "projection" is not defined for raster layers, resulting in an error a few lines down (near 154). Defining the projection just leads to failures further down, wish I had the skillz: QPackage_dialog.py, line 181, in copierCouches DOMTree = Parse(fichierprojet) minidom.py, line 1958, in parse return expatbuilder.parse(file) expatbuilder.py, line 911, in parse result = builder.parseFile(fp) expatbuilder.py, line 207, in parseFile parser.Parse(buffer, 0) xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 2